# How to Convert Array to String

Tags: java

How can I convert a single chunk of string inside an array into string, then I need to split it back into an array with a line such as `<array>.split("\\n+");`

For example (I want to do something like this but I don't know the exact code to make it happen. Where would be the best place to understand this?):

```
String[] myStringArray = {"aa bb cc dd ee ff\n gg hh ii jj kk ll\n mm nn oo pp\n ..."};
String myString = myStringArray.toString();
myStringArray = myString.split("\\n+");
```

Comment: `String myString = myStringArray[0];`?

Comment: You are maybe looking for [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Arrays.toString()
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(Object[]) more details

Comment: Using Arrays.toString() did the job!